# React router rendering two child components instead of just one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to add routes to my application but for some reason there are two components being rendered to the page instead of just one.

My code looks like this (the relevant part):

```
import React from "react";
import Board from "./Components/Board";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import TaskDetail from "./Components/TaskDetail";
import { LanesProvider } from "./Context/lanes.context";
import { TasksProvider } from "./Context/tasks.context";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


function App(props) {
    const getTask = props => {
        return <TaskDetail />;
    };
    return (
        <>
            <LanesProvider>
                <TasksProvider>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Board />
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Board />} />
                            <Route exact path="/board" render={() => <Board />} />
                            <Route exact path="/board/:taskName" render={() => getTask()} />
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </TasksProvider>
            </LanesProvider>
        </>
    );
}
```

Now basically when I'm navigating to "localhost/board/test" I would expect to just see the `<TaskDetail/>` component but instead I get the `<Board />` AND `<TaskDetail/>`.

I didn't expect this to happen because of the `exact` boolean.

FYI: `getTask()` is only returning a component right now because I wanted to get the routes to work first before implementing further logic.

So far I could not find a solution to this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your <Board /> component is not wrapped inside <BrowserRouter> or <Switch>, which mean it will get rendered regardless of whatever routes you are in

Comment: That was it, thanks! @jimmy5312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `<Board />` component outside your `<BrowserRouter>`

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";
import Board from "./Components/Board";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import TaskDetail from "./Components/TaskDetail";
import { LanesProvider } from "./Context/lanes.context";
import { TasksProvider } from "./Context/tasks.context";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";


function App(props) {
    const getTask = props => {
        return <TaskDetail />;
    };
    return (
        <>
            <LanesProvider>
                <TasksProvider>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Board /> --> Remove this component from here
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Board />} />
                            <Route exact path="/board" render={() => <Board />} />
                            <Route exact path="/board/:taskName" render={() => getTask()} />
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </TasksProvider>
            </LanesProvider>
        </>
    );
}
```